# Error using DoCmd.TransferDataBase in PowerShell - 'The Table cannot be exported'

Tags: database, powershell, ms-access, automation

I'm trying to export a MS Access table from a .accdb file for distribution and upload to tables on other db files across a network.

My method call looks like this:

```
$appPath = C:\Users\Me\Desktop\SourceAccessFile.accdb"
$reportpath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\DesiredFileName.mdb"

$Access.DoCmd.TransferDatabase([acDataTransferType]::acExport, "Microsoft Access", $appPath, [acObjectType]::acTable, "TPnPDispatchedExport-WC", $reportPath)
```

With the following $Error value:

```
'' cannot be imported, exported, or copied to Access database files.
```

I can't see what's wrong with either of my paths, both echoed and checked. The format of my arguments seems fine but I'm clearly missing something. Does anyone with fresh eyes see what I might be doing wrong here? Glad to share more if it can be useful.

Comment: The 6th argument is *Destination* which in this case would be the name you want to give to the exported table in the destination database.  But you're giving it the file path to a database.  Not certain that's the cause of your error, but it can't be right.

Comment: Suggest you work out the `TransferDatabase` details in VBA.  Once you have that working, port it to Powershell.

Comment: Thank @HansUp that may be the case but as far as I can see, the issue appears to be with the table I'm referring it to. Changing destination doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: ... but I will look at doing it in VBA first and translating. Perhaps work on something else for a bit. I will revert either way. @HansUp sorry I got distracted and missed the edit window)